# How to transfer data to my SSD from my old HDD?

Tags: ssd, windows-7-backup

I have a ThinkPad w520 and the OS is preinstalled in it and a hidden disk of factory backup for restore. Now I want to replace the old HDD with SSD for the faster speed. Is there a way to move the factory backup to SSD and use this to install the genuine OS?

Comment: hi, I think you should be able to clone whole disk to image using free Seagate Disc Wizard and then load this image onto your SSD including all partitions, bootloader etc. If the procedure will be successfull, you should be also able to install the OS.

Comment: But my HDD is 500GB and SSD 256, how come it will load the partitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Norton ghost, Acronis or similar software to make a backup of old disk. Then you have the choice of either restoring the whole old image to the SSD and do a factory restore. Or you could just keep using your current install and tweak it for the SSD.

However I always recommend clean install over factory installs. Simply because almost all of the factory installs come with a lot of needed bloatware. A clean install of windows 7 also detects that it is installing to a SSD and configures itself for that (e.g. no periodic defrag).

Comment: Is there a better way to install newest drivers from the site rather than installing one by one?

Comment: There is, via driver packs and scripted reinstallations. But that is a lot more work to set up. It is useful if you are going to install a lot of computers (e.g. in a corperate setup). For home users downloading the latest drivers and installing them one by one is usually the fastest and easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have windows key, usually a sticker placed at the bottom of laptop or provided to you with manuals, then you can download win 7 from microsoft website and do a fresh istall on SSD. Make sure you backup data and driver folders from old hard drive.

Comment: Link for a legal ISO download: http://techpp.com/2009/11/11/download-windows-7-iso-official-direct-download-links/  (you will still need a valid key)